# How to display Rout content while running R in AWS Docker

Tags: r, docker, amazon-cloudwatch

We are migrating our R scripts from our local server to run them on AWS Dockers.
But when we do that, the only things we see in Cloudwatch are the real outputs thart R shows on console.

What we want is to see the output like in a Rout file, that shows the outputs and the lines being executed.

Is that possible?

Best regards.